# Is there a command to send a grpc Go lang server to have it output all possible messages it accepts?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am working on a grpc server and keep getting messages like "target server does not expose service (service name)" even though I think the name is correct. Is there a way (in development) to send a message asking the grpc server to just output all possible services it exposes and messages it accepts? This would help with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called server reflection. Luckily, this has been implemented in grpc go, and you can find a tutorial here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/server-reflection-tutorial.md